# Decoding used in Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, information-theory

Using a transposition matrix of size 4 by 6 (4 columns, 6 rows) and key ‘time’ 
decode the following message:

RLAPET HWBUIE EIERSS TELSRT

I am just looking for either a starting point or a step by step guide through the question please.

Comment: As it stands this question is rather light on context to expect a good answer. If you have the definitions then it should just be a case of working through them. If you don't, go back to the person who set the question and complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re told that the key is `time`. This means that the message was written by rows into an array with four columns; since there are $24$ letters, this took six rows. The key `time` was written at the top of the array, so that the `t` was above the first column, the `i` above the second column, and so on. Finally, the letters were read out one column at a time, taking the columns in alphabetical order of the letters in the keyword. Thus, the fourth column, under the `e` of `time`, was read out first, and the first column, under the `t`, was read out last.

If the message had been `This is my note`, the initial setup would have looked like this:

```
time  
----  
THIS  
ISMY  
NOTE
```

The letters of `time` in alphabetical order are `eimt`, so I now read off columns $4$, $2$, $3$, and $1$ in that order to produce `SYE HSO IMT TIN`.

To decipher the given message, reverse the procedure. `RLAPET` is the first column read out, so it must be the `e` (fourth) column of the original array:

```
time
----
   R  
   L  
   A  
   P  
   E  
   T
```

`HWBUIE` was the second column read out, so it must be the `i` (second) column of the original array:

```
time
----
 H R  
 W L  
 B A  
 U P  
 I E  
 E T
```

Continuing in this fashion, we reconstruct the entire initial array:

```
time
----
THER  
EWIL  
LBEA  
SURP  
RISE  
TEST
```

The original message was filled in by rows, so it must have been `THEREWILLBEASURPRISETEST`, and you’ll have no trouble supplying the correct word divisions.